# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object ,sravn

Tags: apex

I am new to apex help me for this, what is the changes i need to do

```
public class MyCustomController{
Public Account acc;
public MyCustomController(){
List<Account> lstAccount  = [select id,Name,Phone,Industry,Website,Active__c,Rating,BillingCity,Description,Fax,
ShippingCity,AnnualRevenue,BillingCountry,ShippingCountry from Account where
id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')];

}
public Account getAccount() {
return acc;
}
public Pagereference saveMethod() {
update acc;
Pagereference pageRef = new ApexPages.StandardController(acc).view();
return pageRef;
}
}
```

Comment: Adding `acc = lstAccount[0];` to the end of the constructor should help providing you do supply the `id` parameter to the page.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of your controller, you are fetching results in lstAccount list, but you are working on acc object. Since acc is not initialized anywhere, it does not hold any data and so you are getting null pointer exception. In your constructor, use the statement

```
acc = lstAccount[0];
```

This will set the first record from the list to acc object. 
Hope this helps.